# coupon code restrict for only some associated products in magento 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I want restrict coupon code some associate products I have one configurable product it have 25 simple products(associate products) 
i have create coupon code to apply only 5 simple product 
if i add separate simple products it working fine but when i add configurable it not working can any one tell how to create

Configurable product :: testconfig
simple products :: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,DG10NYHS, DG10NYLS,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25

what i want is my coupon need to apply DG10NYHS and  DG10NYLS product only.

if i add DG10NYHS product to cart it working fine
if i add configurable products it not working

[image]

Comment: you can condition add in rule

Comment: i have added simple skus only

Comment: like this way ? http://www.screencast.com/t/fftgY29sn

Comment: see my updated conditions

Comment: you can check only one condition add

Comment: it checking two condition working fine for adding direct simple product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89714/discussion-between-pawankumar-and-rakesh-donga).